# View specs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

```
%section.detail
  %h4 #{t('Common.game')}
  %dl.clearfix
    %dt #{t('Common.Name')}
    %dd{title: 'Class Name'}= @configured_game[:class_name] -------- (5)
    - @configured_game[:parameters].each do |parameter|
      %dt= parameter[:parameter]
      %dd{title: parameter[:parameter]}= parameter[:value]
```

When i try to write a spec for this view i get a undefined method [] for nil:Nil class at line 5 . Does anyone have any idea how i could stub that? . I tried doing 
`assign(:@configured_game,[])` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your spec, set the @configured_game instance variable like below

```
assign(:configured_game, {:class_name => "class_name"})
```